# Proper way to display json data from public API URL between controller and view

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, codeigniter

What is the appropriate way to display json data (the whole json string) from a public API URL in CodeIgniter between a controller and view? (The json data changes over time.)

For example the following URL:

```
https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker
```

returns:

```
{"ticker":{"high":1055.91895,"low":730.10101,"avg":893.00998,"vol":34644526.18952,"vol_cur":38351.83433,"last":800,"buy":802.712,"sell":802.711,"updated":1385926730,"server_time":1385926731}}
```

How can I display this with CodeIgniter on my site?

Comment: Do you mean how to you parse that JSON with Javascript and display it on the page?

Comment: That would help but I would like to use the data on the server side too.

Comment: `json_decode` - http://us3.php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker');
$obj = json_decode($json); //returns as an object
echo $obj->ticker->high;  // you can access like this all the values
```